# Alternative to LIST aggregate function in Firebird

Tags: concatenation, aggregate-functions, firebird, firebird1.5

I have a a table Orders:

```
select * Orders order by 2

Ordernumber     Zone
12345           1
12345           2
12345           3
```

What sql would produce the following output?

```
Ordernumber     Zone
12345           123
```

Unfortunately, LIST cannot be used, since this is an old Firebird 1.5xxx. 
Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: The only real option is upgrading to a newer version. Other than that you can write a selectable stored procedure that does this procedurally.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_ZONER(ordernumber  Integer)
returns (zoner varchar(20))
AS
declare variable zone varchar(20) ;
Begin
  zoner = '';
  for 
  select distinct zone from orders 
  where ordernumber = :ordernumber order by zone into :zone  do
  begin
     zoner  =  zoner || :zone;
  end
  SUSPEND;
End
```

and then use

```sql
select * from getzoner(1234)
```